# Cannot execute Binary File for Node Command

Tags: node.js, linux, bash

When i execute :
**/bin/sh -xe node -v**
I get the error : node: node: cannot execute binary file

Please suggest what I need to do to resolve this error.

When i execute below commands:

**file /bin/bash**
Output :/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

**file node**
node: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped

Comment: I just learnt a lot about "cannot execute binary file" which is mostly caused by an incompatible binary. It doesn't look like this in your case. Hmm... Dumb question: Does your node file has executable (aka x) permissions?

Comment: Yes it has when i execute without bash it .. and directly type #node -v i get the required output:
#node -v
v8.1.0

Comment: I could reproduce your problem even in cygwin. I just found out that I can run a self-compiled binary in cygwin's bash (e.g. `$ ./test-int.exe`) but I _cannot_ when I call it this way: `$ bash ./test-int.exe` getting exactly your error. 1st guess: I have to provide full path but this didn't help. I'm still trying to find out what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I played a little bit in my cygwin and got this (for me surprising) result:

```
$ cat >test-int.c <<EOF
> #include <stdio.h>
> 
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>   printf("sizeof (128): %u\n", sizeof (128));
>   printf("sizeof (4294967296): %u\n", sizeof (4294967296));
>   printf("sizeof (281474976710656): %u\n", sizeof (281474976710656));
>   return 0;
> }
> EOF

$ gcc -std=c11 -o test-int test-int.c

$ ./test-int 
sizeof (128): 4
sizeof (4294967296): 8
sizeof (281474976710656): 8

$ bash -xe ./test-int
./test-int: ./test-int: cannot execute binary file

$
```

After some searching I found it. Actually, you and me stumbled into the same trap...

According to `man bash` (close to the top):

> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the
>   -s  option  has  been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the
>   **name of a file containing shell commands**.

Having learnt this, I tried:

```
$ bash -c ./test-int
sizeof (128): 4
sizeof (4294967296): 8
sizeof (281474976710656): 8

$ bash -xec ./test-int
+ ./test-int
sizeof (128): 4
sizeof (4294967296): 8
sizeof (281474976710656): 8

$
```

**Update:**

I just realized another trap – the command line arguments. The following sample illustrates this:

```
$ cat >test-arg.c <<EOF
> #include <stdio.h>             
> 
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>   for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) printf("argv[%d]: '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
>   return 0;
> }
> EOF

$ gcc -std=c11 -o test-arg test-arg.c

$ ./test-arg arg1 arg2 arg3
argv[0]: './test-arg'
argv[1]: 'arg1'
argv[2]: 'arg2'
argv[3]: 'arg3'

$ bash -c ./test-arg arg1 arg2 arg3
argv[0]: './test-arg'

$
```

So, what? The arguments are lost!

```
$ bash -xec ./test-arg arg1 arg2 arg3
+ ./test-arg
argv[0]: './test-arg'

$
```

This time, I found the solution without consulting the `man bash`:

```
$ bash -xec "./test-arg arg1 arg2 arg3"
+ ./test-arg arg1 arg2 arg3
argv[0]: './test-arg'
argv[1]: 'arg1'
argv[2]: 'arg2'
argv[3]: 'arg3'

$
```

To make it *one call*, the command *and* the arguments have to be "quoted together".

Comment: Did you test it with your `node` application? `test-int.exe` is something I did my-self. (I should edit the answer appropriately.)

Comment: Yes I tested with my node application only on linux .. It enter bash shell and is asking for arguments.. like below:
/bin/bash -xec /usr/local/bin/node /u03/node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint --format --out result.json
+ /usr/local/bin/node
>
>
>

Comment: May be, it's worth to **edit** your question and adding this as update. Please, copy the output of shell as well. (Please, don't forget to format the code pieces with the **{}** button in the toolbar.)

Comment: As you can see in my sample, the `-x` causes debug output `+ ./test-int`. Does something like this appear in your case?

Comment: I guess I found the 2nd problem also. Please, see my update.